# Bad Image Position with on writehtmlcell in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf, emoji

When I generate an PDF, I use Emoji Icons.
This works fine, the Emoji's are between chars and words.
But the position is bad.

Example:

[image]

```
<img src="emoji/Emoji173.png" width="18" height="18" border="0" style="margin-bottom: -4px" />
```

The Style -> style="margin-bottom: -4px" -> does not work. :-(

Have someone an idea to set the icon lower?

Comment: What about trying display:inline-block?

Comment: You could try specifying a line-height on both until they look right to you, or forcing the image down 4 pixels with position:relative, and top:4px